# How do I get snd-usb-audio to detach from a device?

Tags: usb, audio, usb-audio

**Context**

I'm working on a reverse-engineered controller for an Arturia AudioFuse over at https://github.com/rhofour/audiofuse-cli that uses libusb (through pyusb). I'm able to find the device, detach the kernel driver from the control endpoint, and change the various settings I intend to. However, I can't figure out how to correctly hand the device back to the snd-usb-audio driver.

One thing that kind of works is detaching every kernel driver from every endpoint on the device, doing my stuff, then attempting to reattach them. This triggers the device to restart itself and when it comes back the kernel correctly grabs it. However, the downside here is that restarting it takes some time and can trigger a loud pop in speakers and headphones so I'd like to avoid this.

**What I think I need to do**

What I'd like to do is detach the snd-usb-audio driver from the device entirely, change the various settings I'm interested in, then re-attach it without restarting the device. I know this is possible because I've been using VirtualBox to pass this device through to a Windows VM and that is able to take the device from snd-usb-audio, use it, then return it to snd-usb-audio without ever resetting it.

What I'd like to know is how I can do this myself.